# Laravel 5 / Eloquent: error when trying to get values from linked tables

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5, relationships

I'm trying to create a simple Laravel 5 app for testing purposes. Everything seem to be set-up correctly (database, tables, etc.) and my model relationships are OK (tested with php artisan tinker).
I still get an error "Undefined property..." and cannot understand how to get values from other linked tables within a view...

/resources/views/orders/index.blade.php

```
<ul>
@foreach( $orders as $order )
<li>Order # {{ $order->id }} - {{$order->status}} - {{$order->products->name}} - </li>
@endforeach
</ul>
```

=> Am I doing something wrong? How can I get the name of the product linked to the order?

```
OrdersController.php
public function index()
{
$orders = Order::all();
return view('orders.index', compact('orders'));
}
```

Here are my tables (migrations):

```
public function up()
{
Schema::create('orders', function(Blueprint $table)
{
$table->increments('id');
$table->timestamps();
$table->string('status');
});


Schema::create('products', function(Blueprint $table)
{
$table->increments('id');
$table->integer('order_id')->unsigned();
$table->timestamps();
$table->string('name');
$table->string('sn');
});
```

Here are my 2 models:

//File: App\Order.php

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Order extends Model {

public function products()
{
return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
}

}
```

//File: App\Product.php

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model {

public function order()
{
return $this->belongsTo('App\Order');
}
}
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: undefined property for what property (which line)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue here is that $order->products gives you collection of products not single product. You can use $order->products->first()->name or iterate over products to get names of each of the products.

Comment: Thank you Anand Patel and Hussam Hussien for your time and your help; I will spend time to understand & test your solutions. However, I must say the solution Smartman gave me is the best solution: his code in my view works perfectly, without even  changing my models or controllers! Thanks a lot my friend.

Answer (score 0):

In your order controller you need to write `with` to retrieve relational data

```
public function index()
{
      $orders = Order::with('products')->all();
      return view('orders.index', compact('orders'));
}
```

**OR**

if you want to retrieve products all the times with order you can specify it in model using with like this

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Order extends Model {

protected $with = 'products';

    public function products()
    {
         return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
    }

}
```

Now when you retrieve order it always retrieve relational data specified using with i.e. products

**view**

In your view you can access product like this as one order has many products

```
    <ul>
    @foreach( $orders as $order )
    <li>Order # {{ $order->id }} - {{$order->status}} - 
     @foreach( $order->products as $product )
         {{$product->name}}
     @endfor
    - </li>
    @endforeach
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you should [read more](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent) about framework that you are working on.

### Step 1:

you should name your model class as a singular name
For example 'category' , and define the table name to be    tbl_products_category

```
    class category extends Eloquent {

     protected $table = 'tbl_products_category';

    }
```

### Step two

You can then  use Eloquent smart methods to select your data with clean code.
on your route.php file.

```
   $product_categories =
   category::where('tbl_product_category_status', '=', 1)->get();
```

Then assign this object to your view :

```
$view = View::make('greeting')
->with('product_categories',$product_categories);
```

### Finally

Put this code on your view

```
    @foreach ($product_categories as $category)
    <li><a href="{{$category->tbl_product_category_id;}}">{{$category
    ->tbl_product_category_name;}}"</a></li>
    @endforeach
```